# Open and close second form with hotkey/keyboard shortcut

Tags: c#, winforms

(I am an novice/beginner when it comes to C# and Winform)

I have a Windows Forms application with 2 forms. The first form is transparent and is just there to show and hide the second form. The second form is an "Overlay" with some buttons. I have a hotkey to open the second form but I can't get it to close the second form with a hotkey. I have tried some different things and googled a lot. The purpose with this application is to open the overlay menu and from that menu you can switch between applications.

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Click thurgh
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr Hwnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
        //
        //Hotkey
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(String sClassName, String sAppName);

        private IntPtr thisWindow;
        private Hotkey hotkey;
        //

        FormOverlay frm = new FormOverlay();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
            this.TransparencyKey = Color.LimeGreen;

            this.TopMost = true;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

            int initialStyle = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20);
            SetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20, initialStyle | 0x80000 | 0x20);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            thisWindow = FindWindow(null, "Form1");
            hotkey = new Hotkey(thisWindow);
            hotkey.RegisterHotKeys();
        }
        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            hotkey.UnRegisterHotKeys();
        }



        protected override void WndProc(ref Message keyPressed)
        {
            Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("FormOverlay");
            if (keyPressed.Msg == 0x0312)
            {
                if (pname.Length > 0) //my latest try
                {
                    frm.Hide();
                    MessageBox.Show("1");
                }
                else
                {
                    frm.Show();

                }


            }

            base.WndProc(ref keyPressed);
        }
    }
}
```

Hotkey.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    class Hotkey
    {
        public enum fsModifiers
        {
            Alt = 0x0001,
            Control = 0x0002,
            Shift = 0x0004, 
            Window = 0x0008,
        }

        private IntPtr _hWnd;

        public Hotkey(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            this._hWnd = hWnd;
        }

        public void RegisterHotKeys()
        {
            RegisterHotKey(_hWnd, 1, (uint)fsModifiers.Control, (uint)Keys.G);
        }

        public void UnRegisterHotKeys()
        {
            UnregisterHotKey(_hWnd, 1);
            UnregisterHotKey(_hWnd, 2);
        }

        #region WindowsAPI
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
        #endregion

    }
}
```

If you have any documentation, article, video or tutorial that contains your answer please post it, too, so I don't ask too many questions in the comments.

Comment: You need to learn how to use the instances of the objects you create. This: `thisWindow = FindWindow(null, "Form1");` is simply `this.Handle`. This: `FormOverlay frm = new FormOverlay();` creates an instance of `FormOverlay` (which is not a Process). You just need this reference to verify whether `frm` is visible or not (`Hide()` just sets `Visible = false`). You need to remove this: `SetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20, initialStyle | 0x80000 | 0x20);`. Use [CreateParams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.createparams) to set the styles of a Control.

Comment: But I'm not really sure what's the use of a transparent Layered Form here: you actually need just one Form (maybe two if you're handling different things and one of them is meant to remain iconized in the tray notification area). + You're not really *handling* the Hotkey ID. See the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61149361/7444103) (that code is part of a UserControl, but it's the same thing).

Comment: Thank you. I will try my best. If i got it correct I need to check if my second form is visible and not running

Comment: In relation to `FormOverlay`, you just need `frm.Visible = !frm.Visible`, also checking whether it's `null`. Bring it to front, eventually. The other parts are more important, though. Also, this: `UnregisterHotKey(_hWnd, 2);` tries to unregister a hotkey you never registered.

Comment: `if (frm.Visible = !frm.Visible) ` Do you mean something like this?

Comment: Nope, that's not even correct syntax. When you receive a Hotkey notification, you just need to invert the `Visible` property value, so just `frm.Visible = !frm.Visible` (and verify that `frm` is not `null`). Of course, you could change the Form's Opacity property instead, to make the Form completely transparent instead of *not visible* (which may have consequences). You could also do that in a timed loop, so the Form will *fade in / fade out*.