# Converting System.Windows.Forms.Keys to the Win32 virtual-key code and modifiers

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, key, keycode

Is there a built-in way to convert a System.Windows.Forms.Keys value to a Win32 virtual-key code and modifiers (a combination of MOD_ALT, MOD_CONTROL, etc.)?

I need a virtual key code and a modifiers int value to pass to the [RegisterHotKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey) native method.

So far I'm using

```
private static int GetModifiers(Keys key)
{
    int modifiers = 0;
    if ((key & Keys.Alt) == Keys.Alt) modifiers |= 0x1;
    if ((key & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control) modifiers |= 0x2;
    if ((key & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift) modifiers |= 0x4;
    return modifiers;
}

private static int GetKeyCode(Keys key) => (int)(key & ~Keys.Control & ~Keys.Shift & ~Keys.Alt);

public bool RegisterHotKey()
{
    int modifiers = GetModifiers(Key);
    int keyCode = GetKeyCode(Key);

    IsRegistered = User32.RegisterHotKey(Hwnd, Id, modifiers, keyCode);
    return IsRegistered;
}
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: `enum KeyModifier : int { None = 0, Alt = 1, Control = 2, Shift = 4, WinKey = 8, NoRepeat = 0x4000 }`. The keys are just, e.g., `(int)Keys.F10`

Comment: Btw, I posted the whole thing here: [Parsing UnregisterHotkey from usercontrol to parent form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61149361/7444103). Not with great success, but perfectly functional :)

Comment: @Jimi Please check the code I have posted. I'm looking for a way to convert any Keys combination (_Ctrl+F11_, _Alt+C_, etc.), that can have any value (for example a shortcut key changed by the user at runtime). In your code the hot key is hard coded.

Comment: It's *hard-coded* because it's an example on how to setup the whole thing. You don't need to switch on the `hotKeyID`, you can use a Dictionary of different HotKeys, with base value on `baseHotKeyID` (so, `baseHotKeyID + 1`, `baseHotKeyID + 2`, etc.). See the call: `RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, baseHotKeyID, KeyModifier.Shift | KeyModifier.NoRepeat, (int)Keys.F11))`. You have an `ID` (`baseHotKeyID`) that you increment for any new HotKey, the `KeyModifier` combo and the associated `Key` can be decided by the User. I use a `List<Class>` objects to store these combinations.

Comment: You have to store these somewhere, since you have to unregister them all when the associated Window handle is destroyed (when the Form is closed or the App terminates). I think I could post the class that handles these registrations. I'll give it a look.