# How would I make a global shortcut which unhides a Windows Form window in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am currently trying to code something in my program which will make a hidden window, which runs in the background, visible once someone puts in a certain keyboard combo (Ctrl + Shift + Q to be exact). I would also like to be able to have the shortcut overlay other programs, so if I was on Chrome, for example, the shortcut would still work, even though the window wasn't active. The program also needs to be able to work without explorer.exe as a shell, as I want to use this as a way to access the desktop after the shell has been replaced. (this means making a hotkey using a program shortcut won't work)

I have tried many uses of KeyDown and even ProcessCmdKey, none of which have worked.

Here is the main form code I have been using which I'd like to implement the code into:

```
namespace windows_shell_opener
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String password = Properties.Settings.Default.Password;
        Boolean hasBeenOpened = Properties.Settings.Default.HasBeenOpened;
        String enteredPassword;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Controls.Add(button1);

            button1.Click += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (password == enteredPassword)
                {
                    Process process = new Process();
                    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                    startInfo.Arguments = "/C explorer";
                    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    process.Start();

                    this.Close(); 
                }
            };
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            enteredPassword = textBox1.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are also the references I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

If you need any more code, I am happy to supply it.
Thanks!

Comment: [RegisterHotKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey) (and un-register).

Comment: @Jimi So how would I use that?

Comment: [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61149361/7444103), for example. You can find a other examples searching SO. -- If you need to handle more than one HotKey, build a Class Handler, which returns the HotKey currently activated based on the ID you provided (which is sent back in `wParam`, as you can see in that code).  -- A warning: HotKeys are *global* keys. If you register a HotKey, you make the Keys you used unavailable to other apps. E.g., if you register just `A`, other apps won't be able to write that char in textboxes.  Don't try to register combinations that include the Win Key.

Comment: @Jimi how would i add multiple keys to the hotkey? the only key I see in the code is shift.

Comment: That's a Modifier Key. You register combinations, as shown in that code, like `SHIFT+F11`. You add an Identifier (an `int` value) associated with the combination of Keys (Modifier + Key). Your Form / UserControl will receive the notification when a HotKey is pressed: you check the ID that's passed back, see to what combination it refers to (or parse `lParam` as described in that code) and act upon it. -- As mentioned, use a class handler to manage multiple HotKey registrations. **Remember to unregister the HotKey(s)**.