# How to determine which key was pressed in a WinProc Message

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a Autoclicker, Mouse Simulator type program.  The functionality I am going for is pressing a key (f8) starts or stops an AutoClicker, pressing a different Key (C) simulates a left mouse button.  I can't use Form events because this form isn't active.

I'm using WM_HOTKEY_MSG_ID, WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP  The hotkey is for the F8 since I only want to toggle a flag, and the keydown and keyup is to simulate mouse down and mouse up.

I'm using this class which I found online, I'm afraid I don't remember where though, however it works just fine.

```
    public class KeyHandler
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

        private int key;
        private IntPtr hWnd;
        private int id;

        public KeyHandler(Keys key, Form form)
        {
            this.key = (int)key;
            this.hWnd = form.Handle;
            id = this.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return key ^ hWnd.ToInt32();
        }

        public bool Register()
        {
            return RegisterHotKey(hWnd, id, 0, key);
        }

        public bool Unregiser()
        {
            return UnregisterHotKey(hWnd, id);
        }
    }
```

When I press one of the registered Keys it fires this event as expected. Which I acquired from the same place as the last method however I have modified this one to be more specific for my case.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
  
        if(m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY_MSG_ID)
        {
            KeysConverter convert = new KeysConverter();
            
            Keys keyData;
           
            if ((Keys)((int)m.WParam) != Control.ModifierKeys)
                keyData = (Keys)((int)m.WParam) | Control.ModifierKeys;
            else
                keyData = (Keys)((int)m.WParam);

         
            //This is the problem area
            if (keyData == Keys.F8)
                HandleHotkey();
            
           
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

The issue I am having is I can't get determine which Key was actually pressed.  I believe I need to use Keys.Keycode, which is a bitmask, on the keyData object but I can't figure out how.  Basically what I want is someway to determine what key was pressed.

I do see that I am never looking for keydown and keyup, I will tackle those issues later, once I figure out the current issue.

Comment: Your HotKey ID is `m.WParam.ToInt32();`, the Key is in HI-LParam: `(Keys)(m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16)`, the modifier key in LOW-LParam: `m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xFF` -- An example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61149361/7444103)  -- You should build a handler class that stores all combination of Keys and Key Modifiers associated with a Message Identifier, so you just need the ID of the message you registered, pass it to your handler which will return the associated keys and modifiers (if any are used).  --  Not clear what this is for: `KeysConverter convert = new KeysConverter();`

Comment: Don't use GetHashCode() to set the id.  Just number them, or use an enum.  You get the number back in WndProc from m.WParam.

Comment: Jimi -  KeysConverter was a relic from past attempts, ignore that, I will have to investigate what you just said, at this moment it's a lot of gibberish to me.  I've been programming for many years now but as a hobby, no formal training so there is a lot I don't know.

Comment: Hans - I did as you suggested and changed the GetHasCode() to a number that I chose, and as you suggested m.WParam ==  that number.  While this may or may not be a perfect solution, for my purposes it works and I appreciate it.  If you wish to post that as an answer I will accept it, if not I will post it as an answer myself and accept it a little later.

Comment: It's pretty simple: 1) Determine a starting ID number to assign to your registered Keys. Starting ID because you can of course register more than one key (ID+1 each Key you register). Hence, you may prefer to use a dedicated class to handle your IDs 2) Assign an ID to a combination of Key + Modifier (e.g., `Control+F11`). 3) When you receive a `WM_HOTKEY` message, pass `m.wParam.ToInt32()` (the ID) to your handler, which will know what combination of Key+Modifier that ID corresponds to. That's all -- I don't know why there's `GetHashCode()` there, it's totally useless and counter-productive.